# using linked list vs large array for searching

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, algorithm

I am implementing some algorithmic changes to the conventional game of life for an assignment.

Essentially, I currently have two options for implementing a multithreaded searching algorithm that improves on the efficiency of a previous algorithm.

- Either search through a linked list using two threads and relay the data to two other threads to process(application is running on a quad core)
- To have a massive preallocated array which will remain largely empty containing only pointers to predefined structures, in which case the searching could be done much faster and there would be no issues in syncing the threads.

Would a faster search outweigh memory requirements and reduce computing time?

It should be mentioned that the array will remain largely empty, but the overall memory allocated to it would be far larger than the linked list, not to mention the index of the furthest most nonempty array element could also be stored so as to prevent the program from searching an entire array.

I should also mention that the array stores pointers to live cell coordinates, and as such is only kept so large as a worst case measure. I am also planning on ignoring any `NULL` values in order to skip array elements who have been deleted.

Comment: Hard to say for sure but the array will suffer from non-locality, ie not efficiently using the cache. But how will you find the neighbours from a linked list?

Comment: The program makes use of an nxmx2 array, the second lay of which stores the neighbours of each element. Since every live cell is referenced you can check the 2nd layer of the live cell and its neighbours co-ordinates to determine who lives and dies. The algorithm is currently 2x faster than a conventional algorithm

Comment: Fast algorithm uses a bitmap (one 64 bit integer representing 64 cells) and implements the neighbour counting with hard-coded binary logic. (Can't remember who said: When in doubt, use brute force).

Answer (score 1):

Game Of Life and searching?????

If you want a multithreaded Game Of Life, calculate line n/2 on its own but don't store it in the array, just in a buffer, run two threads that calculate and store lines 0 to n/2 - 1 resp. lines n/2 + 1 to n-1, then copy the line n/2 into the result.

For four threads, calculate lines at n/4, n/2, 3n/4 first, give each thread a quarter of the job, then copy the three lines into the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is as sparse as most GOL boards, then the list will likely be *much, much* faster. Having a pointer to the next piece of data is way better than scanning for it.

That said, the overall performance may not be better, as others have mentioned.

Comment: the array which stores the pointers to structs containing live cell co-ordinates will remain largely empty and searching will be capped at the furthest non null element, and elements set to null in between that furthest element and the zeroth element will be reused using a stack, making the array search space much smaller. Would this change computing time at all? The amount of space allocated to that array is much more for redundancy than anything, which is why I am hypothesizing this would be a much faster implementation especially with multithreading, but as you mentioned it could be risky.